# I need to unstructure an object to update the variables defined in data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

it's my first post. I need to destructure to update a variable defined in "data", I have the following code snippets. I'm using VUE.

```
data: () => ({
    id: '',
    phone: '',
    email: ''
}),
```

```
methods: {
 async getId(){
   {this.id, this.email, this.phone} = this.$route.query.item
 }
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `({id: this.id, email: this.email, phone: this.phone} = this.$route.query.item);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can assign to existing variables.

The syntax is just a little weird.

This should work

```
({id: this.id, phone: this.phone, email: this.email} = this.$route.query.item)
```

Here's a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-stonebraker-tnppb)

Answer (score 1):

You can't destructure to existing props but to new ones only:

```
data () {
    return {
     item: {
       id: '',
       phone: '',
       email: ''
     }
   }
},
...
methods: {
 async getId(){
   { id, email, phone } = this.$route.query.item
   Object.assign(this.item, { id, email, phone })
```